# wordpress custom post type owl carousel silder

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, owl-carousel

am creating custom post type, i created owl carousel slider function, my question is i want to display the carousel slider in custom post type code.....

function custom_owlcarousel() {

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js", false, '2.0.3', true);

wp_enqueue_script('owl-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/owl/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/owl/owl.carousel.css'); 

wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-trans-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/owl/owl.transitions.css' );
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_owlcarousel' );

Comment: Hey, @Pabru Deva! Welcome to SO. It's not clear what is the specific problem you're facing. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask. Following that guide, you'll more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Hello @Pabru Deva, can you edit your question to remove the [owl] tag plz ? The [owl] is for Ontology Web Language; while you are looking for the tag [owl-carousel]